# Weighing connections between two users using machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Given this data set:

```
User 1: {'Artist': 1, 'Public Figure': 9, 'Film Director': 1, 'Education': 1, 'Musician/Band': 4, 'Musician': 1, 'Community': 1, 'Author': 4, 'Politician': 1, 'TV Show': 2, 'Entrepreneur': 1, 'Journalist': 4, 'Product/Service': 1, 'Defense Company': 1, 'Computer Company': 2, 'Nonprofit Organization': 3, 'Computers & Internet Website': 4, 'Media/News Company': 3, 'Podcast': 1, 'News & Media Website': 2, 'Charity Organization': 1, 'Government Organization': 1, 'Magazine': 1}
User 2: {'Nonprofit Organization': 1, 'Movie': 2, 'Musician/Band': 22, 'Public Figure': 2, 'Entrepreneur': 2, 'TV Show': 2, 'Medical Company': 1, 'American Restaurant': 1, 'Sports & Recreation': 1, 'Media/News Company': 2, 'Sports Team': 1, 'Artist': 3, 'Musician': 1, 'College & University': 1, 'Athlete': 1, 'Music': 1, 'App Page': 1, 'Comedian': 1, 'Interest': 2, 'Product/Service': 1, 'Book Series': 1
```

I believe I can draw conclusions that the strength of the connection is high or low based on the fact that they like or dislike the same categories of topics. What machine learning technique would be best to apply to these connection types, if I had, say, 500 users with categories and weights for each?

Comment: Is there a programming-specific element to this you want us to weigh in on?  Stack Overflow is more for programming help than concept help.  This site might be more helpful: https://ai.stackexchange.com/

Comment: why ML or AI ? This is just some algorithm where you need to test the value and check if it's the same or an opposite.

Comment: I'm not sure what weights to apply to this. I see, regarding the programming element aspect. How can one determine weights to apply to different categories? If everybody likes Movies, that's less interesting. I will move over to ai, though!